Duplicate (copy/paste) file in nautilus on samba share hangs
I am on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I have a samba/cifs share to my NAS mounted in fstab.
It was never a problem to duplicate (copy/paste) a file on that share in Nautilus. Since a few days, however, nautilus becomes unresponsive when doing so.
I tried:

Copy/paste a file from that share to local works
Copy/paste a file to that share from local works
Using cp on the command line from a share and to that share works.
Copy/paste a file from that share and to that share does not work.

Almost the same as described here.
Can someone help me debug this, please?
UPDATE after helpful answer from @Matteo:
Logfile nautilus
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:58.959: nautilus_files_view_notify_selection_changed:Selection changed in window 0x5a52f34afbe0:
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:58.959:    file:///media/nas3/AOT/duplicatesharetestfile.txt
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:58.959: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:58.960: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:58.961: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:58.961: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:58.962: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:59.671: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:59.671: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:59.672: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:57:59.672: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:00.239: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:00.239: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:00.240: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:00.240: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.487: files_added_callback:Files added in window 0x5a52f34afbe0: file:///media/nas3/AOT:
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.487:    file:///media/nas3/AOT/duplicatesharetestfile%20(copy).txt
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.487: async_job_start: ../src/nautilus-directory-async.c:350: starting extension info in 0x5a52f359a620
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.487: async_job_end: ../src/nautilus-directory-async.c:402: stopping extension info in 0x5a52f359a620
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.487: async_job_start: ../src/nautilus-directory-async.c:350: starting extension info in 0x5a52f359a620
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.487: files_changed_callback:Files changed in window 0x5a52f34afbe0: file:///media/nas3/AOT:
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.487:    file:///media/nas3/AOT/duplicatesharetestfile%20(copy).txt
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.487: async_job_end: ../src/nautilus-directory-async.c:402: stopping extension info in 0x5a52f359a620
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.622: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.623: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.623: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.624: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.635: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.636: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:01.637: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.458: async_job_start: ../src/nautilus-directory-async.c:350: starting file info in 0x5a52f359a620
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.458: files_changed_callback:Files changed in window 0x5a52f34afbe0: file:///media/nas3/AOT:
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.458:    file:///media/nas3/AOT/duplicatesharetestfile%20(copy).txt
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.485: files_changed_callback:Files changed in window 0x5a52f34afbe0: file:///media/nas3/AOT:
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.485:    file:///media/nas3/AOT/duplicatesharetestfile%20(copy).txt
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.485: async_job_end: ../src/nautilus-directory-async.c:402: stopping file info in 0x5a52f359a620
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.485: async_job_start: ../src/nautilus-directory-async.c:350: starting extension info in 0x5a52f359a620
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.485: async_job_end: ../src/nautilus-directory-async.c:402: stopping extension info in 0x5a52f359a620
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.485: async_job_start: ../src/nautilus-directory-async.c:350: starting extension info in 0x5a52f359a620
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.485: files_changed_callback:Files changed in window 0x5a52f34afbe0: file:///media/nas3/AOT:
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.485:    file:///media/nas3/AOT/duplicatesharetestfile%20(copy).txt
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.485: async_job_end: ../src/nautilus-directory-async.c:402: stopping extension info in 0x5a52f359a620
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.567: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.568: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.568: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:03.568: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:06.241: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:06.242: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.712: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.713: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.713: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.714: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.714: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.715: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.818: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.819: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.819: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.820: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.820: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): DEBUG: 13:58:08.821: nautilus_file_get_icon: ../src/nautilus-file.c:5358: Called file_get_icon(), at size 32, force thumbnail 16
(org.gnome.Nautilus:15314): Tracker-DEBUG: 13:58:24.003: Freed 1 readonly interfaces

Sorry, no apt logfile on my system.
What might be interesting is a kernel page fault message in syslog at the time of duplicating a file on the cifs share:
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.399811] BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: fffffffffffffffe
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.399831] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.399840] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.399848] PGD 48083f067 P4D 48083f067 PUD 480841067 PMD 0 
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.399868] Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.399880] CPU: 3 PID: 15354 Comm: pool-org.gnome. Tainted: G           O       6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.399892] Hardware name: LENOVO 82KU/LNVNB161216, BIOS GLCN46WW 03/23/2022
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.399900] RIP: 0010:cifs_flush_folio+0x41/0xf0 [cifs]
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400072] Code: 49 89 cd 31 c9 41 54 49 89 f4 48 c1 ee 0c 53 48 83 ec 08 48 8b 7f 30 44 89 45 d4 e8 c9 51 ee d4 48 89 c3 31 c0 48 85 db 74 77 <48> 8b 13 b8 00 10 00 00 f7 c2 00 00 01 00 74 10 0f b6 4b 51 48 d3
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400082] RSP: 0018:ffff9ed64d907ce8 EFLAGS: 00010282
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400094] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: fffffffffffffffe RCX: 0000000000000000
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400102] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400109] RBP: ffff9ed64d907d18 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000000000000
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400115] R10: 0000000000000002 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400121] R13: ffff9ed64d907d60 R14: ffff8ce85c6038d8 R15: ffff9ed64d907d58
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400127] FS:  000078c2cdffb640(0000) GS:ffff8cebdd0c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400135] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400142] CR2: fffffffffffffffe CR3: 0000000224df8000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400149] Call Trace:
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400155]  <TASK>
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400164]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400180]  ? __die+0x24/0x80
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400192]  ? page_fault_oops+0x99/0x1b0
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400208]  ? kernelmode_fixup_or_oops+0xb2/0x140
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400219]  ? __bad_area_nosemaphore+0x1a5/0x2c0
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400232]  ? bad_area_nosemaphore+0x16/0x30
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400240]  ? do_kern_addr_fault+0x7b/0xa0
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400250]  ? exc_page_fault+0x10d/0x1b0
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400262]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400281]  ? cifs_flush_folio+0x41/0xf0 [cifs]
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400358]  ? cifs_flush_folio+0x37/0xf0 [cifs]
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400420]  cifs_remap_file_range+0x16c/0x670 [cifs]
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400483]  do_clone_file_range+0x104/0x2d0
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400493]  vfs_clone_file_range+0x3f/0x150
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400500]  ioctl_file_clone+0x52/0xc0
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400508]  do_vfs_ioctl+0x7e/0x910
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400513]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400519]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400525]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400529]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400533]  ? __fget_light+0xa5/0x120
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400541]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x7d/0xf0
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400547]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x90
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400554]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400559] RIP: 0033:0x78c2faf1a94f
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400605] Code: 00 48 89 44 24 18 31 c0 48 8d 44 24 60 c7 04 24 10 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 08 48 8d 44 24 20 48 89 44 24 10 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <41> 89 c0 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 1f 48 8b 44 24 18 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400609] RSP: 002b:000078c2cdffa690 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400614] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00005a52f3dfa270 RCX: 000078c2faf1a94f
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400618] RDX: 0000000000000021 RSI: 0000000040049409 RDI: 0000000000000022
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400621] RBP: 00005a52f35608a0 R08: 000078c2ac002600 R09: 0000000000000003
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400624] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00005a52f35a1e40
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400627] R13: 00005a52f32ebd50 R14: 00005a52f3d63ca0 R15: 000078c2cdffa928
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400636]  </TASK>
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400639] Modules linked in: rfcomm veth vboxnetadp(O) vboxnetflt(O) vboxdrv(O) xt_nat xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc nls_utf8 cifs cifs_arc4 cifs_md4 fscache netfs ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep overlay amdgpu intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_sof_amd_rembrandt snd_sof_amd_renoir snd_sof_amd_acp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_sof_pci edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_generic snd_sof_xtensa_dsp ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof kvm_amd snd_hda_intel snd_sof_utils snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi kvm snd_hda_codec amdxcp snd_hda_core snd_soc_core irqbypass iommu_v2 rtw88_8822ce crct10dif_pclmul snd_compress snd_hwdep polyval_clmulni rtw88_8822c drm_buddy ac97_bus uvcvideo polyval_generic snd_pcm_dmaengine rtw88_pci gpu_sched videobuf2_vmalloc ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_pci_ps uvc rtw88_core
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400784]  drm_suballoc_helper snd_seq_midi_event btusb snd_rpl_pci_acp6x sha256_ssse3 drm_ttm_helper videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btrtl sha1_ssse3 snd_acp_pci videobuf2_v4l2 snd_pci_acp6x btbcm mac80211 ttm snd_seq aesni_intel btintel snd_pcm drm_display_helper binfmt_misc crypto_simd videodev btmtk snd_seq_device cryptd cec rapl nls_iso8859_1 bluetooth snd_pci_acp5x joydev videobuf2_common snd_timer rc_core cfg80211 mc input_leds snd_rn_pci_acp3x ecdh_generic snd snd_acp_config drm_kms_helper snd_soc_acpi ecc hid_multitouch serio_raw ideapad_laptop wmi_bmof k10temp snd_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit libarc4 soundcore ccp sparse_keymap platform_profile mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid nvme nvme_core hid_generic ahci xhci_pci crc32_pclmul libahci i2c_piix4 xhci_pci_renesas nvme_common video i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid wmi hid
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400937] CR2: fffffffffffffffe
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.400941] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] RIP: 0010:cifs_flush_folio+0x41/0xf0 [cifs]
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] Code: 49 89 cd 31 c9 41 54 49 89 f4 48 c1 ee 0c 53 48 83 ec 08 48 8b 7f 30 44 89 45 d4 e8 c9 51 ee d4 48 89 c3 31 c0 48 85 db 74 77 <48> 8b 13 b8 00 10 00 00 f7 c2 00 00 01 00 74 10 0f b6 4b 51 48 d3
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] RSP: 0018:ffff9ed64d907ce8 EFLAGS: 00010282
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: fffffffffffffffe RCX: 0000000000000000
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] RBP: ffff9ed64d907d18 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000000000000
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] R10: 0000000000000002 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] R13: ffff9ed64d907d60 R14: ffff8ce85c6038d8 R15: ffff9ed64d907d58
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] FS:  000078c2cdffb640(0000) GS:ffff8cebdd0c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] CR2: fffffffffffffffe CR3: 0000000224df8000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
May  7 13:58:01 maurice-IdeaPad-3-15ALC6 kernel: [ 9935.577506] note: pool-org.gnome.[15354] exited with irqs disabled

UPDATE Fixed with kernel update 6.5.0-35-generic

I just tried this on my 22.04 instance. I right clicked on a file in my Home directory and selected Copt to... and then in the Select Copy Destination dialogue selected an fstab mounted share on my Synology NAS (the fstab entry uses cifs in the share mount line) and it worked without issue. I also tried Cut then opened the mounted share and pasted it in to a folder in that share with no issue.

Thank you @graham. Is your home directory on that same cifs share? Because, like I wrote, I only have the problem when source and destination are both on the cifs share. Copy from/to local works, just not when both source and destination are on the (same) cifs share.

no, my home directory in on my internal nvme EXT4 formatted device. The cifs share is on an entirely different device which is formatted as Synology RAID and connected through the LAN

In that case, you have tried something that is not what I describe in my problem. My problem is copy/paste a file FROM the share TO the share.

you can try debugging the nautilus activity by capturing it on the terminal like this, the same activity can be read also in the log file afterward:
$ G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all NAUTILUS_DEBUG="All" nautilus | tee -a nautilus.log

Or if you think that the problem has been caused by an update, you could read into the history of apt and search for some correlation by:
$ less /var/log/apt/history.log

or for older entries
$ less /var/log/apt/history/history.log.1.gz


Thank you Matteo, I have added nautilus log & syslog to the original question.
